# Unable to insert data despite of correct syntax

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have 8 tables in database, 7 of which i am able to insert data successfully, 
using the same syntax there, but unable to insert data into the last one.

i tried displaying the values being passed and they are all correct,

i tried entering the values into database through mysql workbench manually, again correct

php code:

```
<?php
    require "con.php";

    $user_name        = $_POST["email"];
    $user_password    = $_POST["password"];
    $encrypted_password = md5($user_password);

    $firstname        = $_POST["firstname"];
    $middlename       = $_POST["middlename"];
    $lastname         = $_POST["lastname"];
    $employer         = $_POST["employer"];
    $designation      = $_POST["designation"];
    $department       = $_POST["department"];
    $dob              = $_POST["DOB"];
    $birthplace       = $_POST["birthplace"];
    $nationality      = $_POST["nationality"];
    $gender           = $_POST["gender"];
    $currentaddress   = $_POST["curraddr"];
    $permanentaddress = $_POST["permaddr"];
    $state            = $_POST["state"];
    $country          = $_POST["country"];
    $cityofpref       = $_POST["cityofpref"];
    $phone            = $_POST["phone"];
    $mobile           = $_POST["mobile"];
    $website          = $_POST["website"];
    $totalexperience  = $_POST["experience"];
    $workdescription  = $_POST["workdesc"];
    $twitter          = $_POST["twitter"];
    $facebook         = $_POST["facebook"];
    $skype            = $_POST["skype"];
    $linkedin         = $_POST["linkedin"];
    $researchgate     = $_POST["researchgate"];
    $googlescholar    = $_POST["googlescholar"];
    $status           = $_POST["Status"];
    $UG1              = $_POST["UG1"];
    $UG2              = $_POST["UG2"];
    $UG3              = $_POST["UG3"];
    $PG1              = $_POST["PG1"];
    $PG2              = $_POST["PG2"];
    $PG3              = $_POST["PG3"];
    $PHD1             = $_POST["PHD1"];
    $PHD2             = $_POST["PHD2"];
    $PHD3             = $_POST["PHD3"];
    $others1          = $_POST["others1"];
    $others2          = $_POST["others2"];
    $others3          = $_POST["others3"];
    $BroadArea        = $_POST["BroadArea"];
    $MajorArea        = $_POST["MajorArea"];
    $MinorArea        = $_POST["MinorArea"];


    $mysql_qry5 = "Insert into Faculty_Webpresence (Faculty_ID, TwitterID, SeobusID, LinkedinID, Skype_ID, Facebook_ID, GoogleScholarID) values
                                                ('$last_id','$twitter','$researchgate','$linkedin','$skype','$facebook','$googlescholar');";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry5))
        {
            echo " .5";
        }
        else
        {
            echo " '5";
        }



    $mysql_qry6 = "Insert into Faculty_Contact (Faculty_ID, PersonalEmail, OfficialEmail, CurrentAddress, PermanentAddress, Website, Phone, Mobile) values
                                             ('$last_id', '$user_name', '$user_name', '$currentaddress', '$permanentaddress', '$website', '$phone', '$mobile');";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry6))
        {
            echo " .6";
        }
        else
        {
            echo " '6";
        }




    $mysql_qry7 = "Insert into Faculty_Academia (Faculty_ID, UndergraduateUniversity, UndergraduateDiscipline, PostgraduateUniversity, PostgraduateDiscipline, DoctorateUniversity, DoctoratezDiscipline) values ('$last_id', '$UG2', '$UG1', '$PG2', '$PG1', '$PHD2', '$PHD1');";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry7))
        {
            echo " .7 ";


            echo $last_id, $cityofpref, $BroadArea, $MajorArea, $MinorArea,$workdescription;
        }
        else
        {
            echo " '7";
            echo $last_id, $cityofpref, $BroadArea, $MajorArea, $MinorArea,$workdescription;
        }


    $mysql_qry8 = "Insert into Faculty_Interest (Faculty_ID, StateofchoicecityinIndia, BroadArea, MajorArea, MinorArea, InterestDescription) values
                                                ('$last_id', '$cityofpref', '$BroadArea', '$MajorArea', '$MinorArea', '$workdescription');";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry8))
        {
            echo " .8";
        }
        else
        {
            echo " '8";
        }
?>
```

con.php:

```
<?php
    $db_name = "FacultyDB";
    $mysql_username = "root";
    $mysql_password = "<password>";
    $server_name = "127.0.0.1";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);

    if($conn)
    {
        echo "1 ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "0 ";
    }
?>
```

java code:

```
String login_url = "http://127.0.0.1/signup.php";
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));


                String post_data =   URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("firstname", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[3], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("middlename", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[4], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("lastname", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[5], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("employer", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[6], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("designation", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[7], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("department", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[8], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("DOB", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[9], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("birthplace", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[10], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("nationality", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[11], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("gender", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[12], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("curraddr", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[13], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("permaddr", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[14], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("state", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[15], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("country", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[16], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("cityofpref", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[17], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("phone", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[18], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("mobile", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[19], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("website", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[20], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("experience", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[21], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("workdesc", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[22], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("twitter", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[23], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("facebook", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[24], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("skype", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[25], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("linkedin", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[26], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("researchgate", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[27], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("googlescholar", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[28], "UTF-8")
                        +URLEncoder.encode("Status", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[29], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("UG1", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[30], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("UG2", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[31], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("UG3", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[32], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("PG1", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[33], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("PG2", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[34], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("PG3", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[35], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("PHD1", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[36], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("PHD2", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[37], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("PHD3", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[38], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("others1", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[39], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("others2", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[40], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("others3", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[41], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("BroadArea", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[42], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("MajorArea", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[43], "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("MinorArea", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(params[44], "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    result+=line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: See about parametrised queries . Immediately!

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score -1):

your query has syntax error :

$mysql_qry5 = "Insert into Faculty_Webpresence 
(Faculty_ID, TwitterID, SeobusID, LinkedinID, Skype_ID, Facebook_ID,GoogleScholarID) 
values('$last_id','$twitter','$researchgate','$linkedin','$skype','$facebook','$googlescholar');";

remove ';"' semicolon and closing quotation and try

Comment: ok , it is not a syntax error , then could you explain me this?